# Twitter Bootstrap Modal - Capture info from iframe and populate on main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I'm using bootstrap in conjunction with jquery to capture the title of a button selected in a modal then populating the result within an input on the main window. Everything works fine when keeping the modal on the main parent page as you can see from this example:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="chooseTemplateLocal" class="templateSelect input-prepend">
    <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Choose Template&hellip;</a>
    <input type="text" class="template-text" value="No template chosen" >
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Modal - Loaded on same page -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="template-group">
          <div class="template">
              <p>Template Title 01</p>
              <button role="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" name="Company Deal 01">Select</button>
          </div>
          <div class="template">
              <p>Template Title 02</p>
              <button role="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" name="Enroll Benefits 01">Select</button>
          </div>
          <div class="template">
              <p>Template Title 03</p>
              <button role="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" name="Uploaded Template">Select</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
     <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
     <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.template-group > .template > .btn').click(function(){
    // Capture Title
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).data('templateText', name).removeAttr('name');
    $('.template-text').val(name);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MHP5d/24/

I've been asked to load all modal-body content in an iframe/remotely instead of within the main window. The modal is loading fine, but the input no longer is communicating properly to the main window to send the result to the input as in the example.

I can understand why it's not working, I just am not sure how to make it work.

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're saying is you want to dynamically load the content in an iframe into the modal window. I do something similar and this is what I did.

You'll have to load the iframe with ajax. Ill have to dig up the explanations I found.

This is what I did to get it to work. I literally just lifted from one of my projects. So obviously you'll have to change accordingly.

**/home.html**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-href="modal_ancient.html" class="btn btn-          
primary">CLICK ME</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').on('click','a[data-toggle="modal"]',function(e){
 var action = $(this).attr('data-href');
 $.ajax({
  url : action,
  type: "GET",
  success: function(response) {
   $('<div class="modal fade"></div>').html(response).modal();
  }
 });
 e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Then I have my modal content in a separate file.

**/modal_ancient.html**

```
<div style="max-width: 230px;" class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
 <iframe style="border: 0; width: 170px; height: 631px;" src="http://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/album=3938117856/size=large/bgcol=ffffff/linkcol=0687f5/transparent=true/" seamless><a href="http://music.owlphabet.com/album/ancient-whales">Ancient Whales by Ancient Whales</a></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
 </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: Is your modal on the same page as home.html with the body loading an iframe or is the entire modal structure in the modal_ancient.html page?

Comment: it's on it's own page.

Comment: @JosephSjoblom, it's on it's own page. The only thing I have on the main page is the link to pop the modal. "<a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-href="modal_ancient.html" class="btn btn-          
primary">CLICK ME</a>" That refers to the /modal_ancient.html where the entire model is at

Comment: Hi Russell, I couldn't get this to work as I'd hoped. Any way you can share an example on jsfiddle? If not, no biggie. thanks

Comment: @Jospeh, not sure why it's not working for you. That modal is on a seperate html page. It calls it with data-href. I tried to quickly rewrite it on jsfiddle, but was becoming a pain.

Comment: @Joseph, you can go to owlphabet.com to see how it works